# PHP/MySQL Google Chart

Tags: php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

Everyone I am trying to create a google chart with PHP with Database from a local MySQL database. I've done so many times without issues. I work in a warehouse and we have many floors, instead of having charts for each floor, our management team wants both floors on one chart, once I've done this I've received an error 'This table has no columns'. This occured after I joined my F1 table, and F2 Table. Independently they all work perfectly fine. I will attach source code for Combined and individual, I am bashing my head as I can't quite seem to see what the issue is.

Thank you!

**Working Code(Gave sensitive data fake names)**

```
mysql_select_db('db', $con); 

// write your SQL query here (you may use parameters from $_GET or $_POST if you need them)
$query = mysql_query('select BalanceDate, Value 
from fcfinance.DAT_METRICS 
where FC in("warehouse") and metric = "utilization:Simple Bin Count"
and balancedate >= current_date-10 
and Floor = "pa01"
order by balancedate;');

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    /* define your DataTable columns here
     * each column gets its own array
     * syntax of the arrays is:
     * label => column label
     * type => data type of column (string, number, date, datetime, boolean)
     */
    // I assumed your first column is a "string" type
    // and your second column is a "number" type
    // but you can change them if they are not
        array('label' => 'BalanceDate', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Utilization', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $temp = array();
    // each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['BalanceDate']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Value']);

    // insert the temp array into $rows
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

// encode the table as JSON
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

// set up header; first two prevent IE from caching queries
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// return the JSON data
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

**Non-Working Code(Combing both floors onto one chart):**

```
<?php
/* $server = the IP address or network name of the server
 * $userName = the user to log into the database with
 * $password = the database account password
 * $databaseName = the name of the database to pull data from
 * table structure - colum1 is cas: has text/description - column2 is data has the value
 */
$con = mysql_connect('hostname', 'user', 'password') or die('Error connecting to server');

mysql_select_db('db', $con); 

// write your SQL query here (you may use parameters from $_GET or $_POST if you need them)
$query = mysql_query('select * from (select coalesce(f1.BalanceDate,f2.BalanceDate) BalanceDate, 
case when f1.value is null then '0' else f1.value end f1_value, 
case when f2.value is null then '0' else f2.value end f2_value  from (
(select BalanceDate, Value, Floor
from fcfinance.DAT_METRICS
where FC in("warehouse")
and metric = "utilization:Simple Bin Count"
and balancedate >= current_date-10
and Floor = "pa01"
order by floor, balancedate)f1
left join
(select BalanceDate, Value, Floor
from fcfinance.DAT_METRICS
where FC in("warehouse")
and metric = "utilization:Simple Bin Count"
and balancedate >= current_date-10
and Floor = "pa02"
order by floor, balancedate) f2
on f1.BalanceDate = f2.BalanceDate));');

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    /* define your DataTable columns here
     * each column gets its own array
     * syntax of the arrays is:
     * label => column label
     * type => data type of column (string, number, date, datetime, boolean)
     */
    // I assumed your first column is a "string" type
    // and your second column is a "number" type
    // but you can change them if they are not
        array('label' => 'BalanceDate', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'f1 value', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'f2 value', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $temp = array();
    // each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['BalanceDate']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['f1_value']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['f2_value']);

    // insert the temp array into $rows
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

// encode the table as JSON
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

// set up header; first two prevent IE from caching queries
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// return the JSON data
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

Comment: What does your PHP output?

Comment: From the get_json.php file I made it outputs: a blank white page, where the other ones usually shows the raw fields and what is going to be put into chart.

Comment: You need to debug your PHP.  At a glance, I don't see anything that would throw an error, so I suggest testing your SQL to make sure it is working.

Comment: I have this, but I'm trying to make an array_combine() and I had it, but can't remember the format here is what I have now. The SQL works, but the PHP portion for the arrays is not.  foreach($_POST['category'] as $i => $category) 
 { 
   // Get values from post.
   $category = mysql_real_escape_string($category);
   $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value'][$i]);

   // Add to database
   $sql = "REPLACE INTO `oak3_eos_dashboard` (`category`, `value`, `date`) VALUES ('".$category."', '".$value."', curdate())";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
 }

Comment: I'm missing something here - that PHP code is nothing like your question.  If that is from changes you've made to your code, update your question with the changes.  If that is unrelated to the code in this question, open another question.

Comment: OMG!! I'm so sorry! That was a total different question. SORRY, Yes. The SQL works independently perfectly fine in MySQL workbench, and gives me the results I need. But, as soon as I plugged it into the GoogleCharts is when is gave any form of error.

Comment: You need to debug the code.  [This site](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php) has some tips that should help you.  If you get error messages that you can't resolve, update your question with the errors and I'll try to help.

Comment: I got it to work!! I needed "" around my 0's -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that I corrected that works. I made a rookie move, I needed a double quote around 0 as I did with my where clauses.

```
mysql_select_db('fcfinance', $con); 

// write your SQL query here (you may use parameters from $_GET or $_POST if you need them)
$query = mysql_query('select coalesce(f1.BalanceDate,f2.BalanceDate) BalanceDate, 
case when f1.value is null then "0" else f1.value end f1_value, 
case when f2.value is null then "0" else f2.value end f2_value  from (
(select BalanceDate, Value
from fcfinance.DAT_KIVA_METRICS
where metric = "Utilization:Simple Bin Count"
and FC = ("OAK3")
and balancedate >= current_date-10
and Floor = "PaKiva01"
order by floor, BalanceDate) f1
left join 
(select BalanceDate, Value
from fcfinance.DAT_KIVA_METRICS
where metric = "Utilization:Simple Bin Count"
and FC = ("OAK3")
and balancedate >= current_date-10
and Floor = "PaKiva02"
order by floor, BalanceDate) f2
on f1.BalanceDate = f2.BalanceDate);');

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    /* define your DataTable columns here
     * each column gets its own array
     * syntax of the arrays is:
     * label => column label
     * type => data type of column (string, number, date, datetime, boolean)
     */
    // I assumed your first column is a "string" type
    // and your second column is a "number" type
    // but you can change them if they are not
        array('label' => 'BalanceDate', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Floor 1 Utilization', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Floor 2 Utilization', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $temp = array();
    // each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['BalanceDate']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['f1_value']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['f2_value']);

    // insert the temp array into $rows
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

// encode the table as JSON
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

// set up header; first two prevent IE from caching queries
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// return the JSON data
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```